# Replace ' with \' in string using String.replaceAll()

Tags: java, string

Replace **`'`** with **`\'`** using the `String.replaceAll()` is not working.

```
String t="It can't be done";
String title=t.replaceAll("'", "\\\'");
syso(title);
```

Expected output: It can\'t be done

Comment: This is the laziest question ever... But you probably forgot that `String.replaceAll` takes a regular expression as its first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unusual output but you need one extra slash `\`:

```
t.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to double escape the slash.

```
t.replaceAll("'", "\\'")
```